# About definition of topology

Tags: general-topology, definition

let be $m$ a function "$m: X \to \mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(X))$" (and I denote: $m(x) := m_x, \forall x \in X $), $m$ is topology on $X$ if:

2)$ \forall x \in X (\forall t \in m_x(x \in t)) $

3)$ \forall x \in X( X \in m_x) $

4)$ \forall x \in X( \forall t,u \in m_x(t \cap u \in m_x))$

5)$ \forall x \in X (\forall t \in m_x( \exists r \in m_x(\forall y \in r(t \in m_y))))$

6)$ \forall x \in X (\forall t \in m_x( \forall r \subseteq X( t \subseteq r \to r \in m_x)))$

is correct? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks fine. But one usually wants $\emptyset$ to be a topological space, so (1) seems uncommon to me. The rest looks fine.

Comment: The terminology is wrong or unfortunate. $m$ is not a topology in the usual sense of that word. $m$ defines a neighbourhood system, and there is a unique topology $\tau$ on $X$ such that for all $x\in X$, $m_x$ is the system of neighbourhoods of $x$ with respect to $\tau$.

Comment: @DanielFischer, to write "$X$ is topological space" is correct ??

Comment: The normal definition of a topology is as a subset of $\mathcal{P}(X)$ satisfying certain conditions, or one could write it as a function $\mathcal{P}(X)\rightarrow \{0,1\}$. What you have described seems to be some kind of association of neighbourhoods of a point $x$ to each $x$ in $X$. Although this induces, and is induced by a topology, they are not strictly the same kinds of objects.

Comment: @martini, thanks!! :)

Comment: Topology can be defined using either of open sets, closed sets, neighbourhood systems as basic structure. Using open sets is just the today prevalent method.

Comment: @Hagen: However, a *topology* on a set is by definition the family of open sets, whether one defines the space by giving the topology directly, by giving a nbhd system, by describing which nets converge, or whatever.