# formalize definition of topology

Tags: general-topology, definition

In my studies I used [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/534479/about-definition-of-topology) definition of topology, but I am reading on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_topology#A_topology_on_a_set) a different definition... 
I thought to formalize:

**Def**. let be $A$ a set and $B \in \mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(A))$, $(A,B)$ is *topology* if

- $\emptyset \in B$
- $A \in B$
- $\forall X \subseteq B( \bigcup X \in B)$
- $\forall X_1,X_2,X_3,...,X_n \in B((...((X_1 \cap X_2) \cap X_3) ... \cap X_n) \in B)$

It is correct? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: @M.Vinay: Your edit should have been rejected. You have enforced **your** style of writing on the OP. And while it may have been a much cleaner style, it goes against the spirit of the question where the OP asked whether or not what they wrote is correct. Your edit should have appeared as an answer instead.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I think the OP was asking about the content of his definition rather than his notation. Is there any fundamental difference between $X \in \mathcal{P}(Y)$ and $X \subseteq Y$? Anyway, if you think it is important I'll let it be.

Comment: @Гарнак Олэговытц A word about your notation. Instead of writing something like $X \in \mathcal{P}(Y)$ [which says $X$ is an element of the power set of $Y$], you can more simply write $X \subseteq Y$ [which says $X$ is a subset of $Y$], which means exactly the same thing, by definition. You don't need brackets for intersection, you can write $X_1 \cap X_2 \cap \ldots \cap X_n$ or $\bigcap\limits_{i=1}^n X_i$.

Comment: @M.Vinay: Generally, I'd agree with you that the edit was in place. But here the OP asks about the correctness of what they wrote. This includes, in my taste and to some extent, remarks on style. By changing the style of the mathematics you effectively changed the style of the axioms. Not to mention, rendered about a third of my answer moot.

Comment: @AsafKaragila And I'd agree with you if I had changed "topology" to "topological space". I decided not to change that as then I would indeed be making a meaningful change to the question. So let's just not agree on this, hehe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it's okay. But here are two points that I'd change:

1. $B$ is the topology. The pair $(A,B)$ is a topological space.
2. It suffices to require that $\forall X,Y\in B(X\cap Y\in B)$.

   As it is written, the last axiom is very hard to understand, both due to excessive parentheses (intersection is associative, so we can remove all of them anyway) and because it's unclear whether or not $n$ is constant. If it isn't, there should be a quantifier on $n$ before the whole thing; if it is then why not pick $n=2$?

Comment: thanks for answer :) therefore, $\forall n \in \Bbb{N}^{\geq 2}(\forall X_1,X_2,X_3,...,X_n \in B((...((X_1 \cap X_2) \cap X_3) ... \cap X_n) \in B))$ is correct?

Comment: Well, certainly it is true for $n=1$, and for $n=0$ the statement is vacuous, so you might as well write $\forall n\in\Bbb N$ (in particular if you don't include $0$ as a natural number). But as I wrote, you can either omit the parentheses or limit yourself for $n=2$ and just take one intersection.

Comment: certainly, you're right.. :) thanks soo much!