# prove $(\Bbb{R},\{X\mid X\subseteq \Bbb{R} \wedge \forall y\in X(\exists r,s \in \Bbb{R}( y\in ]r,s[\wedge ]r,s[\subseteq X))\})$ is topological space

Tags: general-topology

I must prove the following:

**Prop.**: $(\Bbb{R},K:=\{X\mid X \subseteq \Bbb{R} \wedge \forall y \in X(\exists r,s \in \Bbb{R}( y \in ]r,s[ \wedge ]r,s[ \subseteq X))\})$ is [topological space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/821401/formalize-definition-of-topology)

**Proof.**: $\emptyset \in K $ banally, $\Bbb{R} \in K$ using Archimedian property, but How Can I prove "$\forall X,Y \in K( X \cap X \in K)$" and "$\forall Z \subseteq K(\bigcup Z \in K)$"?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The title is hard to read! Also, I have seen $(x,y)$ used more commonly to denote open intervals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(i) $ X,Y\in K \implies X\cap Y \in K $:

If $X\cap Y = \emptyset $ then we are done, so let us suppose this is not the case. Then exists $ x \in X\cap Y $ and we have intervals $ x\in]r,s[ \subseteq X $ and $ x\in]p,q[ \subseteq Y $. The intersection of these intervals $ ]\max(r,p),\min(s,q)[ $ must contain $ y $ and be contained in $ X\cap Y $ and thus $ X\cap Y \in K $.

(ii) $ Z_i\in K, i\in I \implies \bigcup_{i\in I}Z_i \in K $:

Let $ x \in \bigcup_{i\in I} Z_i = Z $, then there exists a $ j \in I $ such that $ x \in Z_j $. Since $ Z_j \in K $ there exist $ r,s \in \mathbb{R} $ such that $ x\in]r,s[ $ and $ ]r,s[\subseteq Z_j $, but then $ ]r,s[\subseteq Z_j \subseteq Z $. Since $ x $ was arbitrarily chosen this holds for any element $ x $ in $ Z $ and thus $ Z \in K $.